# SQL Server : measuring real-time efficiency by operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time, ssms, powerapps

I've been working on some SQL code to measure efficiency in real-time for some production data. Here's a quick background:

Operators will enter in data for specific sub assemblies. This data looks something like this:

```
ID                      PO      W/S     Status      Operator            TotalTime   Date 
60129515_2000_6_S025    107294  S025    Completed   A                   38          05/08/2020
60129515_2000_7_S025    107294  S025    Completed   A                   46          05/08/2020
60129515_2000_8_S025    107294  S025    Completed   A                   55          05/08/2020
60129515_2025_6_S020    107295  S020    Completed   B                   58          05/08/2020
60129515_2025_7_S020    107295  S020    Completed   B                   47          05/08/2020
60129515_2025_8_S020    107295  S020    Completed   B                   45          05/08/2020
60129515_2000_1_S090    107294  S090    Completed   C                   33          05/08/2020
60129515_2000_2_S090    107294  S090    Completed   C                   34          05/08/2020
60129515_2000_3_S090    107294  S090    Completed   C                   21          05/08/2020
```

The relevant columns are the `Operator`, `TotalTime` and `Date` (note that the date is stored as `varchar(50)` because it plays nicer with Microsoft PowerApps that way).

What I need to do is:

- Aggregate the sum of "TotalTime" grouped by Operator
- Calculate the time elapsed based on a condition:

  - If between 7AM and 4PM, calculate the time elapsed since 7AM of the current day
  - If after 4PM, return the total time between 7AM and 4PM of the current day
- Divide the SUM(TotalTime) by the TimeElapsed (AKA the first list item / second list item) in order to get a rough estimate of labor hours worked vs. hours passed in the day.

This calculation would change every time the query was ran. This will allow the Microsoft PowerApp that is pulling this query to refresh the efficiency measure in real time. I've taken a stab at it already - see below:

```
SELECT
    md.Operator,
    CASE 
       WHEN DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE()) > CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE()))) + '7:00' AND GETDATE() < CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE()))) + '15:45' 
          THEN (SUM(isNull(md.TotalTime, 0)) + SUM(isNull(md.DelTime, 0))) * 1.0 / DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE()))) + '7:00' , DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE())) * 100.0
          ELSE (SUM(isNull(md.TotalTime, 0)) + SUM(isNull(md.DelTime, 0))) / 420 * 100.0
    END AS OpEfficiency
FROM 
    [Master Data] AS md
WHERE 
    md.[Date] = CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETUTCDATE()), 101)
GROUP BY 
    md.Operator
```

**Note**: the `DelTime` is a different column regarding delay times. I am also converting back from UTC time to avoid any time zone issues when transferring to PowerApps.

However, this is horribly inefficient. I am assuming it is because the `Date` needs to be converted to datetime every single time. Would it work better if I had a calculated column that already had the date converted? Or is there a better way to calculate time elapsed since a certain time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to increase efficiency considerably. First, you want to make sure SQL can do a simple comparison when selecting rows, so you'll start by calculating a string to match your date on since your [Date] field is a string not a date.

Second, calculate the minutes in your shift (either 540 for a full shift or scaled down to 0 at 7 AM exactly) ahead of time so you aren't calculating minutes in each row.

Third, when summing for operators, use a simple sum on the minutes and calculate efficiency from that sum and your pre-calculated shift so far minutes.

One note - I'm casting the minutes-so-far as FLOAT in my example, maybe not the best type but it's clearer than other decimal types like DECIMAL(18,6) or whatever. Pick something that will show the scale you want.

My example uses a Common Table Expression to generate that date string and minutes-so-far FLOAT, that's nice because it fits in a direct query, view, function, or stored procedure, but you could DECLARE variables instead if you wanted to.

By filtering with an INNER JOIN on the [Date] string against the pre-calculated TargetDate string, I make sure the data set is pared down to the fewest records before doing any math on anything. You'll definitely want to INDEX [Date] to keep this fast as your table fills up.

All these together should give a pretty fast query, good luck

```
with cteNow as ( --Calculate once, up front - date as string, minutes elapsed as FLOAT (or any non-integer)
    SELECT CASE WHEN 60*DATEPART(HOUR, GETUTCDATE())+DATEPART(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE()) > 60*21 
                    --4PM in UTC-5, expressed in minutes
            THEN CONVERT(float,(16-7)*60) --minutes in (4 PM-7 AM) * 60 minutes/hour
        ELSE --Assume nobody is running this at 6 AM, so ELSE = between 7 and 4
            CONVERT(float,60*DATEPART(HOUR, GETUTCDATE()) + DATEPART(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE()) - ((7+5)*60))
             --Minutes since midnight minus minutes from midnight to 7 AM, shifted by 
             --UTS offset of 5 hours
        END as MinutesToday --Minutes in today's shift so far
        , FORMAT(DATEADD(HOUR,-5,GETUTCDATE()),'MM/dd/yyyy') as TargetDate --Date to search for
            --as a string so no conversion in every row comparison. Also, index [Date] column
)
SELECT md.Operator, SUM(md.TotalTime) as TotalTime, SUM(md.TotalTime) / MinutesToday as Efficiency
FROM [Master Data] AS md INNER JOIN cteNow as N on N.TargetDate = md.[Date]
GROUP BY md.Operator, MinutesToday
```

BTW, you didn't make allowances for lunch or running before 7 AM, so I also ignored those. I think both could be addressed in cteNOW without adding much complexity.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you Robert, this is exactly what I was looking for. Yes you are correct, those two allowances will have to be addressed in the future. If I use this as a function, I can use the production start time as an input (e.g. 7 AM or 6 AM) and such. How would you recommend tackling lunch and breaks? There's an hour lunch break as well as two fifteen-minute breaks. I assume it would be included in the CASE statement for checking the current time. But not sure how to adjust the calculation for that.

Comment: Yes @sykfarhan, if this solution mostly works for you (performance is good) then you could add lunch and breaks as extra lines in the CASE statement so you'd have CASE WHEN now< 7 THEN xxx WHEN now<break THEN yyy WHEN now<lunch THEN zzz ... END. Putting the calculations there means they are run once not repeated for each row in the result or worse the input table.